# Tangency points to a curve (with implicit differentiation)

Tags: calculus, curves, implicit-differentiation, tangent-line

I have the curve $x^2+xy+y^2=1$, whose graph is as follows:

[image]

I'm trying to find the points where the line tangent to the curve is parallel to the line $y = -x$. There are colleagues of mine who answered the points (0.5; 0.5) and (-0.5; -0.5).
I tried to solve by doing the implicit derivation and equating it to -1, which is the slope of the tangent line:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+xy+y^2)=\frac{d}{dx}(1)\leftrightarrow 2x+y+x\frac{dy}{dx}+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0\leftrightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-2x-y}{x+2y}\leftrightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2x+y}{x+2y}=-1\leftrightarrow \frac{2x+y}{x+2y}=1\leftrightarrow 2x+y=x+2y\leftrightarrow y=x$$

The problem is that I have two variables and an equation. I already thought of replacing $y$ with $x$ in the initial curve, but that doesn't respect the condition of the tangent line. How can I find the values of $x$ and $y$, given that I only have one equation?

Comment: Substitute $y=x$ in the equation of the ellipse. This will give $3 x^2 = 1$.

Comment: There are colleagues of mine who answered the points (0.5; 0.5) and (-0.5; -0.5), these points doesn't lie on curve !

Comment: @user215805 The exercise is giving me: ($\sqrt{3}/3$,$\sqrt{3}/3$) and ($-\sqrt{3}/3$,$-\sqrt{3}/3$). Is that the correct answer?

Comment: @Carmen González yes !As copper.hat suggested $$x=1/√3 =√3/3$$ and similarly other one (-ve part)

Comment: Thank you for confirming me. I thought I was wrong in my calculations, but I am glad they are on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the parallels to $y + x = 0$ have the representation $y+x=m$

Substituting $y = m-x$ into the ellipse equation we have

$$
x^2 + x(m-x)+(x+m)^2 = 1
$$

now solving for $x$

$$
x = \frac 12\left(m\pm \sqrt{4-3m^2}\right)
$$

but at tangency we should have $4-3m^2=0$ so the tangent lines are

$$
y+x=\pm\sqrt{\frac 43}
$$

at

$$
x =\frac 12 \left\{-\sqrt{\frac 43}, \sqrt{\frac 43}\right\}
$$